# Trying to use pointer to access private variable outside class, with member functions outside class

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to get my head around pointers so I have been reading and trying things.
Currently I'm trying to put member functions outside the class, but be able to access a private variable from inside the main function. From what I've read this can't be done, unless I have a pointer inside the class.
So I have tried putting a function that returns a pointer to my private variable inside the class, with all other member functions outside the class.
However when I try to read the private variable I run into compile problems.

I've tried reading other posts and trying their solutions, but I'm just getting more confused.
Ideally, I would like to have a member function named "area" outside the class that is passed a pointer to the private variable "radius" and returnss the area.

This is what I currently have:

```
#include <iostream>
#define PI 3.14159;
using namespace std;

class Circle{
private:
    float radius;   
protected:
    float *radPtr = &radius;
public:
    float getRadiusPtr(){  
        return *radPtr;
    }
    void getRadius();
    void showRadius();
};
void Circle::getRadius() {
    cout << "Enter Radius: "<< endl;
    cin >> radius;
}

void Circle::showRadius(){
         cout << "Radius: " << endl;
    }

float Circle::area(*radPtr){
    float ar;
    float r = this.getRadiusPtr();
    ar = PI * r * r;
}


int main(){
    Circle c1;
    c1.getRadius();
    c1.showRadius();
    cout << "Area: " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Dam He's trying to learn about pointers. Telling him not to use a pointer doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: I tried using ideone and it worked fine
However when I use VisualStudio and g++ it gives me the error I described earlier.

Comment: Just update the  ideone.com/49nrHE  with the pointers as you requested, also using pow() to make that clear.

Comment: Remove the ';' from your macro PI, as it gets expanded as -> float a =  3.14159`;`* *r * *r; (note the semicolon after PI). Check here http://ideone.com/z9Hvx9

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried compiling in ideone using c++ 5.1 and got the same error I was getting with VisualStudio and g++
So that explains that problem.

Comment: `float Circle::area(*radPtr){` is an error: (1) you cannot define a member function that you didn't declare in the class definition, and (2) the parameter is missing a type specifier

Comment: This class will cause a dangling pointer if objects are copied or moved (the copy of `radPtr` will point to the old class which may no longer exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `&radius` outside a member function, since there's no specific object whose `radius` member it should get the address of.

Furthermore, your `getRadiusPtr()` function isn't even returning a pointer. It's just returning the value of `radius`.

Try:

```
float *getRadiusPtr() {
    return &radius;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
int main() {
    Circle c1;
    c1.getRadius();
    c1.showRadius();
    float *r = c1.getRadiusPtr();
    float a = PI * *r * *r;
    cout << "Area: " << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/xnKiLk)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
When I try to compile I get the error for the line
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘float’)
     float a = PI * *r * *r;

Comment: Update: I can use cout to print the value of r, but when I try to use it in the area calculation I get compile errors.

Comment: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘float’)
     float a = PI * *r * *r;

Comment: Your definition of `Circle::area()` has a syntax error. `(*radPtr)` is not a valid argument specification. It's not clear what that argument is even for. Since this is a member function it can access `radius` directly, it doesn't need a pointer.

Comment: Sounds like you wrote `float r` instead of `float *r` on the previous line.

Comment: I used the code you suggested and removed Circle::area
int main(){
    Circle c1;
    c1.getRadius();
    float *r = c1.getRadiusPtr();
    c1.showRadius();
    cout << "r= " << *r << endl;
    float a = PI * *r * *r;
    cout << "Area: " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}

Gah! I thought the formating would come through :(

Comment: I put back the code in the original question. Otherwise the answer doesn't make sense. How will people know what you were doing wrong that I corrected?